# object literal and Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, updatepanel, master-pages

What I've got is an ASP.NET MasterPage/ContentPage, where the ContentPage utilizes an UpdatePanel with UpdateMode set to "Conditional". This ContentPage is basically a MultiView that has 3 views: Setup, Confirm, and Complete.  I've got navigation buttons that when clicked, go to the server, do what they need to do and finally update the UpdatePanel so it can come back.  My problem lies in my JavaScript.

I have the following Global object literal named `PAGE`:

```
PAGE = {

    panel : undefined,
    currentView: undefined,

    buttons : {

        all : undefined,
        cont : undefined

    },

    views : {

        setup       : {},
        confirm     : {},
        complete    : {}

    }

};
```

My `PAGE.init()` function looks like this:

```
PAGE.init = function() { console.log("PAGE.init() fired");

    this.panel    = $('div[id$="Panel_Page"]');
    this.currentView  = this.panel.find('input[id$="Hidden_CurrentView"]').val();
    this.buttons.all  = this.panel.find('input[type="submit"]');
    this.buttons.cont = this.panel.find('input[id$="Button_Continue"]');

    this.buttons.all.click(function() { PAGE.panel.hide(); });

    switch (this.currentView) {

        case "confirm"      : this.views.confirm.init();    break;
        case "complete"     : this.views.complete.init();   break;
        default             : this.views.setup.init();      break;

    }

};
```

And last, but not least, it all gets kicked off by:

```
// Fire events on initial page load.
PAGE.init();

// Fire events for partial postbacks.
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(PAGE.init);
```

My issue is that when it first fires `Page.init()` everything is great, however, when you click a button it immediately throws an error of: **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'all' of undefined**.  Now I've tried to figure this out, but I'm at a loss.  It seems as though this happens to **ANY** nested object literal off of the root of `PAGE`.  The immediate properties like `PAGE.panel` work just fine, but as soon as you need access to `PAGE.buttons.all` or `PAGE.views.setup`, it throws this error.  I have never seen this before.

Any ideas out there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `this` inside of the `PAGE.init()` function, I used `PAGE` and that corrected the issue.  Apparently `this` was not referring to `PAGE` but rather `PAGE.init`.  Still not sure why, as I do this elsewhere and it works.

For instance, the following use of `this` works and it's no different than how I use it in my OP:

```
PAGE.views.setup = {

    buttons : { 

        all : undefined,
        cont : undefined

    },

    init: function() {

        var self = this,
            buttons = self.buttons;

            buttons.all = PAGE.panel.find('input[type="submit"]');

        buttons.all.click(function() { alert(this.id + " clicked"); });

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a getter for your panel property.  Seeing as everything else appears to be a property of panel this should do it - you might be losing the reference to panel during the postback, so instead of getting the object once, get it every time:

get_panel: function() { return $get("Panel_Page"); }

Again, if I just have this.panel = $get(myElement) and then my partial page update destroys the node that was returned to this.panel when I created my object initially, this.panel will become undefined.  Use a getter.

Hope that helps - happy coding.

EDIT:

Actually - now that I look at it again, you'll probably want to use getters for all of your properties instead of relying on get_panel().find(..) for currentView, for example, I'd do another getter there:

get_currentView: function() { return $get("Hidden_CurrentView", this.get_panel()); }

B

Comment: Sorry for my late response, I've been on vacation.  I'm not sure how I would be losing my reference when I'm firing the init() function every single request.  Not to mention, the panel isn't even where my problem lies as the base property of buttons is what is coming back undefined for some reason. Take another look at my explanation at the bottom.  Maybe it will make better sense as to what I'm doing.

Comment: @Scott - have you tried a getter in place of any of the properties?  Just wondering if you don't think this is the problem, or you tried and it didn't work and you know it's not the problem. Every time I've had an issue similar to this it is because I'm losing the reference to the node. Would it be possible to post a little more code so I can try to reproduce the issue on my end?

Comment: What you are missing is that it's not about the properties referencing to the DOM.  Losing that reference is for people that aren't re-initializing on every partial postback, which I am as evident by the last line of code in my example. The issue I'm having is that my object literal property `PAGE.buttons` is becoming undefined somehow.